# Does 'A countable infinite Cartesian product of countable sets is not necessarily countable' violate induction principle?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have two theorems about Cartesian product:

1. A *finite* Cartesian product of countable sets is countable;
2. A *countable infinite* Cartesian product of countable sets is *not* necessarily countable.

To prove the first theorem, we can show

- Firstly, we can prove $A\times B$ is countable,
- Secondly, suppose it is true for $n-1$, i.e. $X=A_1\times A_2\times \ldots \times A_{n-1}$ is countable, we prove the case for $n$ by the fact $A_1\times A_2\times \ldots \times A_{n-1}\times A_{n}=X\times A_{n}$ is in fact the product of two countable sets, in above we know it is still countable.

The above method to prove the first theorem is exactly the **mathematical induction**, which should show the theorem is true for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{+}$, so it should works for countable infinite unions.

However, we may use Cantor diagonal method to prove at least $\{0,1\}^w$ is not countable, thus the second theorem is also right. Does this means that the **mathematical induction** is wrong?

---

**EDIT**: After the following discussions, I have the answer:

The key point is that any element $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ is always a *finite* number, thus induction principle only guarantee the theorem is true for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, i.e. for any finite number.

When discuss a countable infinite union, it is **infinite number** of unions, this infinite number no more belong to $\mathbb{Z}_+$, thus can not be guaranteed by induction principle.

Comment: Of course this can't possibly mean that induction is wrong, because induction is right. Induction shows that the product of $n$ countable sets is countable - it simply doesn't show anything about the product of infinitely many. "For all $n\in\Bbb N$" only says something about _finite_ values of $n$.

Comment: No.  Your understanding of induction is flawed.  You prove something holds for all natural numbers $n$ by induction.  It does not follow that the same thing holds for $\infty$.  Or maybe you think (falsely) that $\{0,1\}^\omega$ is the union of the sets $\{0,1\}^n$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich That make sense. Thank you.

Comment: It is not the same question as the ones I marked as duplicate, that's true. But it's the same answer: induction proves "for all finite", but does not prove "there is an infinite object whose restriction works for all finite".

Answer (score 3):

The theorem that "for all finite $n$, $\mathbb{N}^n$ is countable" is true. The "theorem" that "$\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is countable" is not true. Induction on $\mathbb{N}$ shows that something is true for arbitrary finite naturals, but not for $\mathbb{N}$ itself.

I understand induction as justifying that "if I can build the truth of a statement out of its truth for smaller statements, then I can climb the ladder all the way to any desired endpoint": if I can show $P(n+1)$ from $P(n)$, then I can show $P(1000)$ by showing first $P(1)$, then $P(2)$, and so on.
But I can't hope to show $P(\infty)$ this way, because my building procedure will never get there. To justify full transfinite induction, you need an additional induction step, one that applies at this sort of limit.

Comment: Can I understand in this way? the theorem is true for arbitrary $n\in\mathbb{N}$ just means it is true for a finite $n$ as any element of $\mathbb{N}$ is finite. While when we discuss a countable infinite union, it is **infinite number** of unions, *this infinite number no more belong to $\mathbb{N}$*, thus can not be guaranteed by induction principle?

Comment: @XLiu Yep, that looks about right.

Answer (score 2):

Your first proof shows that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the porduct $A_1\times\cdots\times A_n$ is finite but, this not say nothing about $\mathbb{N}$ itself. In the last case you need a transfinite induction argument and as you see it is false for the first limit ordinal.